# Function calls in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have defined a JavaScript object, inside which I have two functions `test1` and `test2`.

When I call  `test1` inside `test2` using `this.test1()`, it says

> `test1` is not a function

When I call `test1` inside `test2` using `objectname.test1()` it works fine.

Any reason why I can not call the other function using `this`?

```
    servicesFilteringObject = {

       init: function(){
         // Created Checkboxes dynamically and associated handleFilter on onclick of it

       },
       handlePrimeryContent: function(){
         // Some code

       },
      handleFilter : function(){
           servicesFilteringObject.handlePrimeryContent();// works
           this.handlePrimeryContent(); //does not work
      }
 }

    servicesFilteringObject.init();
```

Comment: It is really so difficult to post code?

Comment: Show code. Including the code you use to call `test2`.

Comment: If you post your code, somebody will be able to tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: You are doing something wrong ;) That is all we can say for now.

Comment: The logic itself [works](http://jsfiddle.net/vFqhz/) so change your code according to this and it will work.

Comment: Sorry guys .I have added the code.

Answer (score 1):

If "handleFilter" is invoked as

```
servicesPrimaryObject.handleFilter();
```

then `this` will reference that object ("servicesPrimaryObject").  However, if you pass a reference to that function to some other function, perhaps as an event handler, then when invoked from that other context there'll be no `this`.  You can use "bind()" to fix that:

```
somethingElse(servicesPrimaryObject.handleFilter.bind(servicesPrimaryObject));
```

That will ensure that `this` inside the function will always be the right object when the function is invoked at some later point.

Comment: OK - @Gopal note that ".bind()" is not present on old browsers, but the [MDC documentation for bind](http://goo.gl/bSW3L) includes a very solid piece of code you can use to add it where necessary.